# Excel , if function, ifs,

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, ifs, vba

```
I assume x is the number I'm going to analyze and "y" is as "male" or "female" and "z" is as age group.
```

x is a number that the result will be "underweight", healthy " or overweight". but x which is actually the BPI is not the same for male and female. eg, if x = 21 then depends on gender and age it would be categorized as either "underweigh", "healthy " or overweight".

```
 Function BAI(x As Integer, y As String, z As Integer) As String


 If x < 21 And y = "female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

 Elseif 22 <= x <= 33 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 34 <= x <= 38 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "overweight"

ElseIf x >= 39 And y = "Female" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 23 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 24 <= x <= 35 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 36 <= x <= 41 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

ElseIf x >= 42 And y = "female" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 25 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 26 <= x <= 38 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 39 <= x <= 43 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

ElseIf x >= 44 And y = "female" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "obese"

ElseIf x <= 8 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "Underweight"

ElseIf 9 <= x <= 21 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 22 <= x <= 26 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "overweight"

ElseIf x >= 27 And y = "male" And 20 <= z <= 39 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 11 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 12 <= x <= 23 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 24 <= x <= 28 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

ElseIf x >= 29 And y = "male" And 40 <= z <= 59 Then
    BAI = "OBESE"

ElseIf x <= 13 And y = "male" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "UNDERWEIGHT"

ElseIf 14 <= x <= 25 And y = "male" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Healthy"

ElseIf 26 <= x <= 30 And y = "male" And 60 <= z <= 79 Then
    BAI = "Overweight"

 End If

 End Function
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly and for more readability. The question is very likely to be closed in the format its written.

Comment: Please what you already tried and a well formatted display what you input and what is supposed to be returned.

Comment: As a hint, given no example, I would suggest IF() and VLOOKUP() may work.

Comment: @SolarMike 
i think i need VBA for my case, i have 3 variables which they all are dependent. age, gender and BPI. Bpi is a number. this number must be analyze base on the user's age and gender. eg. people who their age is between 20-39 if they are male and their BPI < 8 then they are "underweight" for female is different. if they are 20-39 and female and bpi < 21 then they are underweight

Comment: It is noticed that you gave Alan Wage the same response as you gave me... If you put your data in two tables : on male one female then lookup etc can work - much of this depends on how you structure your data and this also controls how easy it is to change or update the values . if you have them all "hardcoded" in the function then updating a value is difficult : a table value can be changed quickly while the calculation proceeds as set.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your desired result using the IF workbook function.  To get multiple criteria in a single IF condition use the AND() and OR() functions.  To create if - elseif type logic, nest added IF() functions inside the appropriate sections.  as an example

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1="Male", A2>20),AND(A1="Female",A2>30)), IF(A3>200,"overweight","healthy"),"otherstuff")
```

This should get you started down the right path.

Comment: i think i need VBA for my case, i have 3 variables which they all are dependent. age, gender and BPI. Bpi is a number. this number must be analyze base on the user's age and gender. eg. people who their age is between 20-39 if they are male and their BPI < 8 then they are "underweight" for female is different. if they are 20-39 and female and bpi < 21 then they are underweight.

Comment: For complex logic, VBA provides results that will be much easier to read and maintain.  Just create a function that takes your three variables as parameters and returns the desired result string.  Then call that function in the cell.